# ActiveRecord bulk data, memory grows forever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, activerecord, bulkinsert

I am using ActiveRecord to bulk migrate some data from a table in one database to a different table in another database. About 4 million rows.

I am using find_each to fetch in batches. Then I do a little bit of logic to each record fetched, and write it to a different db. I have tried both directly writing one-by-one, and using the nice activerecord-import gem to batch write.

However, in *either* case, my ruby process memory usage is growing quite a bit throughout the life of the export/import. I would think that using find_each, I'm getting batches of 1000, there should only be 1000 of them in memory at a time... but no, each record I fetch seems to be consuming memory forever, until the process is over.

Any ideas? Is ActiveRecord caching something somewhere that I can turn off?

**update 17 Jan 2012**

I think I'm going to give up on this. I have tried:
* Making sure everything is wrapped in a `ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do`
* Adding `ActiveRecord::IdentityMap.enabled = false` (I *think* that should turn off the identity map for the current thread, although it's not clearly documented, and I *think* the identity map isn't on by default in current Rails anyhow)

Neither of those seem to have much effect, memory is still leaking.

I then added a periodic explicit:

- `GC.start`

That seems to slow down the *rate* of memory leak, but the memory leak still happens (eventually exhausting all memory and bombing).

So I think I'm giving up, and deciding it is not currently possible to use AR to read millions of rows from one db and insert them into another. Perhaps there is a memory leak in MySQL-specific code being used (that's my db), or somewhere else in AR, or who knows.

Comment: without seeing code, I haven't the faintest clue.

Comment: The code is pretty straightforward doing pretty much just what is described. Here's the actual file, i can provide a simplified demonstration case without the surrounding setup and dynamic creation of AR model, etc if there's still too much cruft here.  https://github.com/team-umlaut/umlaut/blob/e583824dd15520c146e3cd020d762591b179803d/lib/tasks/umlaut_migrate_permalinks.rake

Comment: Hey @jrochkind did you find the solution for this problem. Please share even I'm facing the same issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: nope, i gave up on it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest queueing each unit of work into a [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque)  queue . I have found that ruby has some quirks when iterating over large arrays like these.

Have one main thread that queue's up the work by ID, then have multiple resque workers hitting that queue to get the work done.

I have used this method on approx 300k records, so it would most likely scale to millions.

Answer (score 0):

Change line #86 to `bulk_queue = []` since `bulk_queue.clear` only sets the length of the arrya to `0` makeing it impossible for the GC to clear it.