# Avoid heroku R14 error with large create loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have an async Resque job that creates many associated objects inside a loop that I can't seem to avoid heroku's ever-popular R14 error with.

```
  has_many :associated_things

  ...

  def populate_things
    reference_things = ReferenceThings.where(some_criteria).map(&:name) # usually between 10 k and 20k strings
    reference_things.each do |rt|
      self.associated_things << AssociatedThing.create name: rt
    end
  end
```

Some things I've tried:

- wrapping the create loop in an `ActiveRecord::Base.uncached` block
- manually running `GC.start` at the end of the loop
- adding an `each_slice` before `.each`

Is there a way to rewrite this loop to minimize memory usage?

Comment: use a queue, handle it in there

Comment: @phoet what type of queue did you have in mind?

Comment: resque, sidekiq, whatever you can use for batching your request work.

Comment: @phoet maybe I should have been more explicit, but this is happening inside a Resque job, not a web request; but even so, why would moving it to Resque necessarily help with a memory problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alex Peachey had some good suggestions, but ultimately, @mu had the right idea in the first comment.

Transitioning to raw SQL is the only way I could find to make this work.  Some suggested methods are here:

http://coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/

I used the mass insert method and it works fine.

It should be said that it's far from clear to me why this is necessary.  Apparently instantiating hundreds of thousands of AR objects -- even outside of a web request, asynchronously -- causes a memory leak.  Maybe this just simply isn't the sort of thing Rails/AR was designed to do.

Related question, perhaps the same issue:  [ActiveRecord bulk data, memory grows forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674047/activerecord-bulk-data-memory-grows-forever)

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas that may help:

Since you are just pulling `nam`e from `ReferenceThings`, don't grab the full object and then just grab the `nam`e. Instead do something like this:

```
reference_things = ReferenceThings.where(some_criteria).pluck(:name)
```

That will do a better query grabbing just the names and give you an array. Much cheaper memory wise.

I noticed you are putting all the `AssociatedThing`s you are creating into an array as you go. If you don't actually need an array of them then just creating them will be better. If you do need them, depending on what you need them for you could create them all and then query the database to grab them again and loop over them with `find_each` which will grab them in batches.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'putting the AssociatedThings into an array`.  The `has_many` association on `self` is an array. Added code to clarify.

Comment: oh I see, I didn't realize this code was inside a model that had a `has_many associated_things`. Instead of `<<` you should do `associated_things.create(name: rt)` and use the association to create the objects, but that doesn't have much to do with your memory/performance issues so you can ignore that part of my answer and just slim down the first part by using pluck to get your names.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think the map I'm doing amounts to the same thing.

Comment: It does not do the same thing. That's my point. Your function is doing a query like `select * from reference_things where some_criteria` and then it's taking all those fields on all those records and creating instances of `ReferenceThing` and filling in the data in those model instances and then you are mapping over that and taking out just the name. My way is doing `select name from reference_things where some_criteria` and returning an array of those names. There is no object creation.

Comment: I see.  Well, in any case, this piece isn't what's causing my problem, it's the loop that follows, but this change will still improve memory performance.

Comment: Another thing you could do in that second loop, is instead of using `<<` and instead of using my suggested `associated_things.create(name: rt)`, just do `AssociatedThing.create(name: rt, some_id: id)`. I don't know what model this lives in but basically whatever the foreign key in AssociatedThing is, set it directly instead of active record doing it. That way you are just creating a bunch of AssociateThing objects but not keeping references to them.